# c# order map grid coordinates

Tags: c#, dictionary, coordinates

I have a list of map grid coordinates (i.e.34.45343,-128.24398) that constitute a road however the list is not in any order.  How do I list the coordinates in order from one end to the other end? I have methods that will find the bearing and distance between two coordinates that may be beneficial to the ordering.

Answer (score 0):

It's certainly possible to find the shortest route through all points in such a list, this is called the Travelling Salesman Problem. But it sounds to me like your data is not in a well-defined form. How can an unordered list   describe a "road" if you don't even know whether the road goes from A to B or from C to D? Maybe the road is deliberately not the shortest possible route due to obstacles...

Comment: I need to define a road from end to end.  The list of coordinates are points that I know are on the road so I just need to order them.

Comment: So you know the starting and ending points, and only the points in between are in unknown order?

Comment: How do you define end to end then? From an arbitrary starting point to an arbitrary ending point, visiting all other points along the way?

Comment: An end is a coordinate with only one other coordinate associated to it in the chain of coordinates and associations.  The challenge is finding the end points and ordering the coordinates in between.

Comment: Ok, so you just want the shortest possible path from any point to any point. This is just TSP with an extra node added to the graph with distance 0 to all other nodes to make it acyclic.

Comment: Say I have 15 coordinates that I know are on a specific road.  I want to find an end point, and then find the next coordinate that is closest to it.  Then, I want to find the coordinate that is closest to that coordinate and so on until I reach the end.This may be one way of addressing the issue but I'm suspect there are other, possibly more efficient, ways of addressing it.